# AVPlayer was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayeritem

I am creating a simple media player app.  My App is crashed when first link is played and I clicked second link in uitableview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        arrURL = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=148820", @"http://www.kcrw.com/pls/kcrwmusic.pls",@"http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=175821",@"http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=148820",@"http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=70931",nil];
        url = [[NSURL alloc] init];    
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        return [arrURL count];
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;
    }
     cell.textLabel.text = [arrURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedSongIndex = indexPath.row;
    url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[arrURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self setupAVPlayerForURL:url];
    [player play];

    //[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
- (IBAction)btnPlay_Click:(id)sender {

    [player play];
    AVPlayerItem *item = player.currentItem;
    [item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial| NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew| NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld| NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior context:nil];
}
- (IBAction)btnPause_Click:(id)sender {

    [player pause];
}

- (IBAction)btnStop_Click:(id)sender {

    [player pause];
}
-(void) setupAVPlayerForURL: (NSURL*) url1 {
    AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url1 options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

    player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem]; **//Application Crashed**
    [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
}
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"timedMetadata"])
    {
        AVPlayerItem *item = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
        NSLog(@"Item.timedMetadata: %@",item.timedMetadata);
        NSLog(@"-- META DATA ---");
        //        AVPlayerItem *pItem = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
        for (AVMetadataItem *metaItem in item.timedMetadata) {
            NSLog(@"meta data = %@",[metaItem commonKey]);
            NSString *key = [metaItem commonKey]; //key = publisher , key = title
            NSString *value = [metaItem stringValue];
            NSLog(@"key = %@, value = %@", key, value);
            if([[metaItem commonKey] isEqualToString:@"title"])
            {
                self.lblTitle.text = [metaItem stringValue];
            }
        }
    }
    if (object == player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");
        } else if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Ready to Play");
        } else if (player.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");
        }
    }
}
```

I got this message when App crashed.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x165297c0 of
>   class AVPlayer was deallocated while key value observers were still
>   registered with it. Current observation info:
>    (  Context: 0x0, Property: 0x1661d5d0> )'

*Application crashed only in IOS 8 in IOS 7 works fine.*
What I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I had a similar problem. It worked fine in iOS 7, and now it crashes in iOS 8.

The solution was to remove the observer, before releasing the object.

When you replace or allocate a new object for a member, you're releasing the old object, so you need to remove the observer first :

```
-(void) setupAVPlayerForURL: (NSURL*) url1 {
    AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url1 options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    if (player != nil)
        [player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem]; 
    [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
}
```

And similarly in btnPlayClick ( in case it is pressed without btnStop_Click being pressed) :

```
- (IBAction)btnPlay_Click:(id)sender {
     if (player != nil && [player currentItem] != nil)
         [[player currentItem] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata"];
    AVPlayerItem *item = player.currentItem;
    [item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial|     NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew| NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld| NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior context:nil];
    [player play];
}
```

Comment: I put this     if(player!= nil)
{
    if(player.currentItem != nil)
    {
          [player.currentItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
     }
}  instead of if (player != nil)
        [player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"]; and working great for me.

Comment: Hi guys, I am also stuck with this issue, was searching for a solution for last 2 days. Please help me to fix this.

I have posted the question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838356/avplayeritem-was-deallocated-while-key-value-observers-were-still-registered-wit

Comment: i implement you code but get error
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <Player 0x178232e40> for the key path "status" from <AVPlayer 0x17820a6e0> because it is not registered as an observer.'

Comment: This give exception that "Cannot remove an observer <AudioPlayerViewController 0x1570020e0> for the key path "status" from <AVPlayerItem 0x174201930> because it is not registered as an observer."

Comment: @AbuzarAmin use try catch for this.  `@try {
                [player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
            } @catch (NSException *exception) {
                
            } @finally {
                
            }`

Comment: Thanks for such a simple solution @Ralph, I wasted my days searching for the solution

Answer (score 3):

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self.player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:nil];
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little context around your solution?

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

When using KVO you must balance calls to `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` with calls to `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` (see the [KVO programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html)).

Try removing the view controller as an observer when the stop button is tapped e.g.

```
- (IBAction)btnStop_Click:(id)sender {
    [[player currentItem] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata"];
}
```

Comment: Application crashed. Crash Log :'Cannot remove an observer <playerScreenViewController 0x17e933b0> for the key path "timedMetadata" from <AVPlayerItem 0x17dc9a10> because it is not registered as an observer.' Application crashed only in IOS 8 device.

Comment: mmcombe is correct, except the error refers to the AVPlayer's status'  KVO. just change his answer to [[player]removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];

Comment: My application is crash in IOS 8 and following is my crash log: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x15edf250 of class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it."

Answer (score 0):

I did meet the similar issue when using AVPlayer, the crash log info says:

> An instance 0x174034600 of class AVKeyPathFlattener was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info:  (  Context: 0x0, Property: 0x17405d6d0> )

As what Apple recommended, what I originally did is adding observer after initialize my AVPlayerItem object, and remove observer in the observer's dealloc method. Because my observer class kept a strong reference on my AVPlayerItem object, so it should not be deallocated before my observer object was deallocated. I really don't know why this happens.

So I tried solved this problem by using [`BlocksKit`](https://github.com/BlocksKit/BlocksKit), it works fine for me right now.

Answer (score 0):

It's wise to verify first if the key is being observed or not before removing the observer with a `@try @catch`, like so:

```
@try {
    [self.player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:nil];
} @catch (id anException) {
    //do nothing, obviously it wasn't attached because an exception was thrown
    NSLog(@"status key not being observed");
}
```